# GWT - IE - form anchor tags

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, spring-security

I have a spring security + GWT app which redirects to Main.html after successful login. I want to retain fragment information after login is done. I followed the instruction mentioned at: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1067 but it doesn't seems to work with IE.

Anyone encountered similar problem and resolved it?